# Create a binary variable based on intervals and two variables - age categories

Tags: r, if-statement, binary, data.table

I am trying to create variables where if an age group overlaps an interval a  1 is put in place and if not a 0 ( for missing values has become an issue I realised when posting). I have yet to find a relevant example on stack or one that I am able to reproduce (see ivs/IRanges and missing values below).

Here is my dput:

```
structure(list(`Est. Lower Age Range` = c(18, 18, 50, 50, 50, 
65, 18, 18, 18, 18, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 0.5, 16, 16, 16, 16, 
16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 65, 65, 16, 16, 16, 16, 65, 65), `Est. Upper Age Range` = c(49, 
49, 64, 64, 64, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 65, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 65, 65, NA, NA, NA, NA, 65, 65, NA, 
NA)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-34L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000002118266d280>)
```

I tried several packages including ivs, lattice, and IRanges one of which would not allow  values in the variables. The base coding that I attempted is as follows:

```
Flag_Prep$`0-2` <- ifelse((Flag_Prep$`Est. Lower Age Range` > 0 & Flag_Prep$`Est. Lower Age Range` <= 2) |
                            (Flag_Prep$`Est. Upper Age Range` > 0 & Flag_Prep$`Est. Upper Age Range` <= 2),
                          1, 0)
Flag_Prep$`0-5` <- ifelse((Flag_Prep$`Est. Lower Age Range` > 0 & Flag_Prep$`Est. Lower Age Range` <= 5) |
                            (Flag_Prep$`Est. Upper Age Range` > 0 & Flag_Prep$`Est. Upper Age Range` <= 5),
                          1, 0)

Flag_Prep$`5-17` <- ifelse((Flag_Prep$`Est. Lower Age Range` >= 5 & Flag_Prep$`Est. Lower Age Range` < 18) |
                             (Flag_Prep$`Est. Upper Age Range` >= 5 & Flag_Prep$`Est. Upper Age Range` < 18),
                           1, 0)

Flag_Prep$`18-64` <- ifelse((Flag_Prep$`Est. Lower Age Range` >= 18 & Flag_Prep$`Est. Lower Age Range` < 65) |
                              (Flag_Prep$`Est. Upper Age Range` >= 18 & Flag_Prep$`Est. Upper Age Range` < 65),
                            1, 0)
Flag_Prep$`65+` <- ifelse(Flag_Prep$`Est. Lower Age Range` >= 65 | Flag_Prep$`Est. Upper Age Range` >= 65,
                          1, 0)
```

Which results in:

```
structure(list(`Est. Lower Age Range` = c(18, 18, 50, 50, 50, 
65, 18, 18, 18, 18, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 0.5, 16, 16, 16, 16, 
16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 65, 65, 16, 16, 16, 16, 65, 65), `Est. Upper Age Range` = c(49, 
49, 64, 64, 64, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 65, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 65, 65, NA, NA, NA, NA, 65, 65, NA, 
NA), `0-2` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 0, 0, NA, NA), `0-5` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA), `5-17` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA), `18-64` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA), `65+` = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1)), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -34L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000002118266d280>)
```

If an age group spans an interval (5-17 for example) I want there to be a 1. Currently, this works for 0.5-17 being flagged for several groups, but when there is 0.5-65 only the under 2, under 5, and over 65 have a 1 variable, but the two middle intervals show 0.

This makes sense from a coding perspective, but I am confused as to how to rectify this. As I mentioned above, I also now realise that I need to determine how to handle situations where one of the age brackets are missing (and they are supposed to be missing).

**EDIT**

I should also mention that the following causes an error with or without the first NA line

```
Flag_Prep$`5-17` <- NA

Flag_Prep$`5-17` <- ifelse((Flag_Prep$`Est. Lower Age Range` >= 5 & Flag_Prep$`Est. Lower Age Range` < 18) |
                             (Flag_Prep$`Est. Upper Age Range` >= 5 & Flag_Prep$`Est. Upper Age Range` < 18) |
                             (Flag_Prep$`Est. lower Age Range` < 5 & Flag_Prep$`Est. Upper Age Range` > 17),
                           1, 0)

# Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, `5-17`, value = logical(0)) : 
#   replacement has 0 rows, data has 9584
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: A 1 for every interval that the age range exists in ie has start, end, or spans. In the second dput you can see that the row with age 0.5-65 has ones for the early age range and for 65+ but not for 5-17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rearrange the comparisons a little and you're set (code simplified because `Est. Lower Age Range` is too long a variable name):

```
dt[is.na(upper), upper := lower]
dt[, c("0_2","0_5","5_17","18_64","65+") :=
       lapply(.(lower <= 2 & upper > 0,
         lower <= 5 & upper > 0,
         lower <= 17 & upper > 5,
         lower < 65 & upper >= 18,
         lower >= 65 | upper >= 65), as.integer)
]
```

The reason this works is because it does! Consider all six scenarios - partial match from the lower bound, partial match from the upper bound, totally enclosed match either way, and non-matches on either side:

```
        0       2
        |-------|

             |----|      - lower is <= 2, upper is > 0     = TRUE
     |----|              - lower is <= 2, upper is > 0     = TRUE
          |----|         - lower is <= 2, upper is > 0     = TRUE
    |--------------|     - lower is <= 2, upper is > 0     = TRUE
 |----|                  - lower is <= 2, upper is NOT > 0 = FALSE
                  |----| - lower is NOT <= 2, upper is > 0 = FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Using *foverlaps*:

```
# add row id, used later for merging back to original data
Flag_Prep[, id := .I ]

#foverlaps doesn't work with NAs, set uppper NAs same as lower values
Flag_Prep[, x1 := `Est. Lower Age Range`, ]
Flag_Prep[, x2 := ifelse(is.na(`Est. Upper Age Range`),
                         `Est. Lower Age Range`,
                         `Est. Upper Age Range`) ]

# ranges table, I set upper limit to 100, set to Inf if you like:
rr <-  data.table(x1 = c(0, 0, 5, 18, 65),
                  x2 = c(2, 5, 17, 64, 100),
                  match = 1)

# key both tables then foverlap, then reshape long-to-wide using dcast
setkey(Flag_Prep, x1, x2)
setkey(rr, x1, x2)
res <- foverlaps(Flag_Prep, rr
                 )[, x1_x2 := paste(x1, x2, sep = "_")
                   ][, dcast(.SD, id ~ x1_x2, value.var = "match", fill = 0)]

# merge on id, drop the id column after merge if needed
merge(Flag_Prep[, c(3, 1, 2)], res, by = "id")
```

Output:

```
#     id Est. Lower Age Range Est. Upper Age Range 0_2 0_5 18_64 5_17 65_100
#  1:  1                 18.0                   49   0   0     1    0      0
#  2:  2                 18.0                   49   0   0     1    0      0
#  3:  3                 50.0                   64   0   0     1    0      0
#  4:  4                 50.0                   64   0   0     1    0      0
#  5:  5                 50.0                   64   0   0     1    0      0
#  6:  6                 65.0                   NA   0   0     0    0      1
#  7:  7                 18.0                   NA   0   0     1    0      0
#  8:  8                 18.0                   NA   0   0     1    0      0
#  9:  9                 18.0                   NA   0   0     1    0      0
# 10: 10                 18.0                   NA   0   0     1    0      0
# 11: 11                 65.0                   NA   0   0     0    0      1
# 12: 12                 65.0                   NA   0   0     0    0      1
# 13: 13                 65.0                   NA   0   0     0    0      1
# 14: 14                 65.0                   NA   0   0     0    0      1
# 15: 15                 65.0                   NA   0   0     0    0      1
# 16: 16                  0.5                   65   1   1     1    1      1
# 17: 17                 16.0                   NA   0   0     0    1      0
# 18: 18                 16.0                   NA   0   0     0    1      0
# 19: 19                 16.0                   NA   0   0     0    1      0
# 20: 20                 16.0                   NA   0   0     0    1      0
# 21: 21                 16.0                   NA   0   0     0    1      0
# 22: 22                 16.0                   NA   0   0     0    1      0
# 23: 23                 16.0                   NA   0   0     0    1      0
# 24: 24                 16.0                   NA   0   0     0    1      0
# 25: 25                 16.0                   65   0   0     1    1      1
# 26: 26                 16.0                   65   0   0     1    1      1
# 27: 27                 65.0                   NA   0   0     0    0      1
# 28: 28                 65.0                   NA   0   0     0    0      1
# 29: 29                 16.0                   NA   0   0     0    1      0
# 30: 30                 16.0                   NA   0   0     0    1      0
# 31: 31                 16.0                   65   0   0     1    1      1
# 32: 32                 16.0                   65   0   0     1    1      1
# 33: 33                 65.0                   NA   0   0     0    0      1
# 34: 34                 65.0                   NA   0   0     0    0      1
#     id Est. Lower Age Range Est. Upper Age Range 0_2 0_5 18_64 5_17 65_100
```

Comment: Cheers, I was it is useful to have these packages as it makes these techniques much easier